# is it possible to anchor a control to another control?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, .net-4.0, controls, anchor

Is it possible to anchor a control to another control?

Lets say i want my Button1 to keep its 4px distance from Textbox1 control without
using FlowLayoutTable control?

> "Why would be this advantageous?" - one could ask

Well let's say you have a `SplitContainer` with a vertical splitter and you have `Textboxes`
in `SplitContainer.Panel1` which are anchored to the left and right but their maximum size's
width is smaller than you allow to the `SplitContainer.Panel1's` width to have (maybe
because you want text to show up there or because additional padding or whatever,you name it)

Now let's say you also have a button next to `Textbox1` and you dont want `Textbox1` to be
overlapped by the `Button1` because its extends to far.

If i want to have my `textbox` fill the `SplitContainer.Panel1` in a fashion that it leaves space for
`Button1` control while still both of them are anchored to the right how would i do it?

Comment: Hard to visualize from the question.  Anchor is appropriate for simple layout.  Implement custom layouts by subscribing the SplitterMoving event or a control's LocationChanged or SizeChanged event and changing the Location or Size property.

Comment: @Hans Thanks, i figured it would be a workaround or more probably the PROPER WAY to do it, i was just wondering if it is possible, but your answer raises another questions in me, which i may or may not ask here or in another question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I extensively use TableLayoutPanels and FlowLayoutPanels to accomplish this.  For you specific circumstance I would use a TableLayoutPanel with three columns and a row for each TextBox.

Column 1: Auto-width, contains Labels all with `AutoSize = True`.
Column 2: 100% width, contains TextBoxes all with `Anchor = Left, Right`.
Column 3: Auto-width, contains the Button in the appropriate row.

Next, I set all text boxes, except for the one next to the button, `ColumnSpan = 2`.  Then just put the TableLayoutPanel in the SplitPanel and set `Dock = Fill`.

Answer (score -1):

it will be a sequence in live which should be flow out from left and keep working lets the right side should be layout.

1. List item safty cares should be provided.
2. List item all things that use in this method should be provided and be check;